# SSH.NET Session Timeout on multithread

Tags: c#, multithreading, ftp, session-timeout, ssh.net

I have the below for a multi-threaded FTP process. The MaxThread is 4 as our destination client has capped us at 4 threads.

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(workerThreads, completionPortThreads);

        foreach (var loan in fileList)
        {
            // Create an MRE for each thread.
            var handle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            // Store it for use below.
            handles.Add(handle);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FtpProcess, Tuple.Create(loan, handle));
        }
        // Wait for threads to finish.
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles.ToArray());
```

Inside FtpProcess method the connection is created and the QueueUserWorkItem waits for an open thread to continue. But the connection will not occur. I receive a Session Timeout error in this.

```
private static void FtpProcess(object loanObject)
{
    var tuple = (Tuple<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>, ManualResetEvent>)loanObject;
    var loan = tuple.Item1;
    var client = new SftpClient(removed for security but this is filled in);

    if (!client.IsConnected)
    {
       client.Connect();
    }
```

Now, if I don't use the QueueUserWorkItem and just use new Thread(FtpProcess).Start then it works and connects multiple times until the cap issue takes place.

Am I missing something or completely misunderstood the entire underlying code for this .NET process?